# gcc -Wparentheses warns for b=1; !a & b but not !a & 1

Tags: c, gcc

Consider following short program:

```
int main() {
    int a = 5, b = 1, c;
    c = !a & b;
    c = !a & 1;

    return c;
}
```

Does anyone know why gcc gives a warning for  `b = 1; c = !a & b;` but not for `c = !a & 1;`?

```
$gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:3:9: warning: suggest parentheses around operand of '!' or change '&' to '&&' or '!' to '~' [-Wparentheses]
     c = !a & b;
```

My gcc version is 8.3.1 (I tried with one other version and the same thing happens).

I'm often surprised how 'smart' gcc is. And this one looks like a very easy problem to figure out. So why still a warning for the first one?

Comment: I dunno if it's much help, but I get the same effect with GCC 9.2.0, even when including `-O3` in the compiler options.  I wondered if the absence of optimization might make a difference — apparently not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning comes into play when you have logical operators and bitwise operators in the same expression, as you would typically want either one or the other but not both.

The reason you don't see the warning in this case:

```
c = !a & 1;
```

Is because 1 is a boolean value and so both `&` and `&&` will have the same effect in this expression.

If the constant were any value other than 1 or 0 it triggers the warning.

Comment: But shouldn't gcc know that b=1 and treat it the same as the line below?

Comment: @hko It's apparently not looking that closely at the flow, but only at a single line.  With a variable of type `int` it doesn't try to figure out the value but it knows if you give it a constant.

Comment: Okay looks like in this case gcc is just not clever enough to understand b is always 1. I even tried with `static const int b = 1` and same warning happens. I'll accept your answer unless someone can tell me a reason why there should still be a warning for the `b = 1; c = !a & b;` case.

Comment: `!(a & 1)` might differ to `(!a) & 1` however, isn't that what the warning is  meant to be about?